# Error " Index exceeds Matrix dimensions"

Tags: matlab, visualization

I am trying to read an excel 2003 file which consist of 62 columns and 2000 rows and then draw 2d dendrogram from 2000 pattern of 2 categories of a data as my plot in matlab. When I run the script, it gives me the above error. I don't know why. Anybody has any idea why I have the above error?

My data is here:
http://rapidshare.com/files/383549074/data.xls

Please delete the 2001 column if you want to use the data for testing.

and my code is here:

```
% Script file: cluster_2d_data.m

d=2000;  n1=22;  n2=40;  N=62

Data=xlsread('data.xls','A1:BJ2000');

X=Data';

R=1:2000;

C=1:2;

clustergram(X,'Pdist','euclidean','Linkage','complete','Dimension',2,...

'ROWLABELS',R,'COLUMNLABELS',C,'Dendrogram',{'color',5})
```

Comment: What line does the error occur in? Did you try debugging it?

Comment: The line which contain this code: clustergram(X,'Pdist','euclidean','Linkage','complete','Dimension',2,... 'ROWLABELS',R,'COLUMNLABELS',C,'Dendrogram',{'color',5}) 



the last line in the code

Comment: When you get the error, type "whos" to see the sizes of your variables. This will help with the debugging.

Comment: Yes, i tried debugging it and i think the error lies in a function called "clustergram.

Comment: If the error lies in clustergram, have you tried `edit clustergram` -- a lot of Matlab functions are written in Matlab and this may reveal the root of your problem.

Comment: I did open clustergram and the error is in line 223 as hown below

Error in ==> clustergram at 223
    [hAxes,hImage,hDen] = create2DClustergram(clustStruct);

I am sure why it is making having error at that line. That si why i need you wxperts to help me out as i am new to matlab.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After the `xlsread` statement you should get a `2000x62 double` matrix `Data`. Then you transpose it and assign to `X`, so `X` is `62x2000` matrix. In the `clustergram` vectors for the properties `RowLabels` and `ColumnLabels` are supposed to match the size of your `Data`, but you pass a 2000-length vector as `RowLabels` and 2-length vector as `ColumnLabels`. This might cause the error.

What version of MATLAB are you using? It looks like pretty old, since you have `clustergram` as function, but in later versions of Bioinformatic Toolbox it was redesigned as object. In R2010a your code would generate

> "`ROWLABELS` size does not match data"

but I'm not sure what it would be in old version.

Try to remove `RowLabels` and `ColumnLabels`, as well as other properties. Do you still get the error?

Comment: I also have my doubts about the property value for `dendrogram`.

Comment: I have removed the RowLabels and ColumnLabels and the error disappear. Thank Yuk for that suggestion. But why can't i have those lebels and will it make any difference in having the labels or not having it?
Thanks

Comment: You surely can have the labels, but their size should match number of rows and columns in your data matrix. Try `R=1:62; C=1:2000;` (although it's the same as default labels).