# i have an error "Index exceeds matrix dimensions"

Tags: matlab

i have an error "Index exceeds matrix dimensions" in matlab code . 
the error appeared in second line of this code

```
for i=1:2    
layer = I4(:,:,i);   
intensity(i) = double(median(layer(mask)));    
end   
intensity  
expressionLevel = log(intensity(1)/intensity(2))
```

this code is a part of a long program

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error " Index exceeds Matrix dimensions"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776510/error-index-exceeds-matrix-dimensions)

Answer (score 1):

If there is no 3rd dimension in I4, when i=2 you will get this error. Try this in MATLAB:

```
I4=rand(3,3)
I4(:,:,1) % This will not give you an error.
I4(:,:,2) % This will give you an "Index exceeds matrix dimensions" error.
```